# How do I make program with c# to check to see if a word is a palindrome?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd

so i'm trying to make a program (text based) that can scan a word you type into it to see if it's a palindrome or not so just a true or false outcome i'm a beginner with c# so please help me out! 
So far this is all i have done.

```
//Name space
namespace PalindromeChecker
{
    //Class
    class Program
    {
        //Function
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type the word");
            ConsoleKeyInfo Keyinfo = Console.Readkey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code and indicate where you've run into difficulties. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try with some search on Google. You can get lots of blogs with this.

Comment: Do an internet search for "reverse c# string", use a method of your choice (read many, learn what the differences between them is and gain knowledge along the way) then do `if (str == Reverse(str))` to determine if a palindrome

Comment: I have not gotten very far i have been trying to research it and came up with a idea to get the program to save the word the person has typed temporarily and check to see if the first and last letter is the same and work it's way inwards until it gets to the middle or comes back with a error so far all i have written is //Name space
namespace PalindromeChecker
{
    //Class
    class Program
    {
        //Function
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type the word");
            ConsoleKeyInfo Keyinfo = Console.Readkey();
 
        }
    }
}

Comment: This question is very broad. Can you please show us some things you have tried so far? We are here to answer specific questions, not to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A palindrome is a sequence of characters that is the same whether read forward or in in reverse. So to determine if a string is a palindrome, we can compare the string with its reverse, it is one.

So how can you create a reverse of a string? If you look at the [`String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string) definition, you'll see it implements `IEnumerable`. Now the `System.Linq`  namespace offers the [`IEnumerable.Reverse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This can be used to reverse a string:

```
var str = "oxo";
var reversed = str.Reverse();
```

However, this returns an enumeration of `char`, not a string. So [`string.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991828%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is needed to turn `reversed` into a string. Having done that, we now have:

```
var str = "oxo";
var reversed = string.Concat(str.Reverse());
```

To test if they are the same, simply compare them:

```
if (str == reversed)
{
    // we have a palindrome
}
```

A "gotcha here is that if `str` is `null`, you'll get a null exception with `str.Reverse`. That can be handled with a null check. So we can then simplify the whole thing down to:

```
if (str != null && str == string.Concat(str.Reverse()))
{
    // we have a palindrome
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 string word = "hi"; ;
                char[] wordArray = word.ToCharArray();
                char[] revWordArray = wordArray.Reverse().ToArray();
                int count = 0;
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < wordArray.Length; i1++)
                {
                    if (wordArray[i1] == revWordArray[i1])
                    {
                        count++;
                    }

                }
                if (count == wordArray.Length)
                {
                    bool a = true;
                }
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain how this works? @Sweta

Comment: @plan122, seriously, not only do you want someone to hand you code on a plate, you want them to then explain it to you? Wow.

Comment: @DavidArno I didn't want the code handed to me all i wanted was to be pointed in the right direction as i am a complete noob as this I'm not even going to use that code i want to do it myself i just need a little helping hand

Comment: @plan122, OK, in that case please see my answer for a fully explained, and very simple, way of achieving what you want to do.